# Extremely basic PHP and Javascript - submit/function not working

Tags: javascript, php

Ok, it's been forever since I've looked at web programming at all, and now I feel like a complete moron because I cannot get this to work.

This site, http://adam.goucher.ca/parkcalc/index.php, has a simple web page with some PHP, and a straight Javascript. It works perfectly. It's just a calculator and form elements, where you select dates and category and then press submit it with a "Calculate" button.

However - I'm trying to copy the site to another place, and here the problems start. There's only the index.php file, the css file (which isn't really necessary, of course), a gif file (not necessary) and the js file. So, I copy the source code from the index.php file and the js file to another server address, making sure to keep the file names. Only relative paths, as far as I can see.

However, it doesn't work at all on the new site. When I press the submit/calculate button, nothing at all happens. What the heck kind of obvious thing am I missing here? It's just a simple submit form and javascript...

Comment: Can you link us the the site that *doesn't* work?

Comment: Sounds like it's triggering a JS error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you copy the php file.

If you downloaded it with your browser you are missing all the php logic. So basically it will not calculate anything, just show you what you see if you load that page in your browser!

Comment: Oh my god. Of course. I knew I was missing something very basic about web programming/scripting. Argh! Thanks.